# Ошибка Visual Studio 19, Пожалуйста дождитесь окончания команды редактора

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Начинает дико бесить уже, что только не делал и настройки сбрасывал и VS преустонавливал никак не хочет исправляться не знаю может проблема с обновлением в VS или в винде но я хз уже что делать

Comment: У ошибки есть какой то сценарий воспроизведения, логи, текст исключения или еще что в таком духе? Вы же ничего не привели, на какую помощь вы рассчитываете?

Comment: Сценарий простой, при написании кода или нажатия tab выскакивает окошко с надписью "Пожалуйста дождитесь окончания команды редактора" нет никаких исключений, просто выскакивает это окно и сильно тормозит сама среда начинает лагать, зависать

Comment: Как то пробовали решить? Откатить/переставить настройки студии или саму студию или плагины к студии?

Comment: Переустанавливал саму студию, сбрасывал настройки, устанавливал не много другую версию студии ничего не помогает

Comment: Плагины какие то используете? Попробуйте их все заблокировать.

Comment: Нет не использую, вообще никаких

Comment: Многие плагины ставятся проямо вместе со студией (всякие там azure плагины и прочее) - попробуйте всех их отключить.

Comment: Эхх нет не помогло, отключил все что есть в настройках "управление расширением" все так же

Comment: [оч похожий случай](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/851366/please-wait-for-an-editor-command-to-finish-1.html)

Comment: БЛ**** наконец-то, оказывается мне мешал git, пришлось самому додумывать, заметил что когда что либо пишу в коде git сохраняет изменения и видимо либо конфликтовал с визуолкой или я как то не правильно создал git ну в общем удалил репозиторий и все, теперь GIT нет в проекте и все работает норм с утра уже мучаюсь с этим. Надеюсь кому то поможет

Comment: запостите ответом, чтобы сохранилось для истории и для индексаторов.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается мешал git, удалил репозиторий и все пришло в норму, скорее всего сам настроил что-то не так

но если вам это не помогло то может это поможет https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/851366/please-wait-for-an-editor-command-to-finish-1.html